# Is there a query that can fetch data from another blade and then print or save it as a pdf?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a web application project where I need to print selected or all the information about that specific person I tried using datatables, it works but it only prints what's inside the table. I need the information about that person which is in another blade.php I was wondering if I there is a code that I could use to link blades using query I'm just new to using laravel

I'm using Laravel framework latest version.

```
<div id="example_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper">
<p class="large"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> All</p>
    @if($joinCount == 0)
    <center><p>There's no payslip</p></center>
    @else
    <table id="exampleid" class="display" style="width:100%"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID Number</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Department</td>
            <td>Cut-off</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($joinn as $join)
           <tr>
            <td>{{$join->idnumber}}</td>
            <td>{{$join->first_name}} {{$join->middle_name}} 
                             {{$join->surname}}</td>
            <td>{{$join->department}}</td>
                    <td>{{$join->cut_off}}</td>
            </tr>
                @endforeach
    </tbody>
        </table>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exampleid').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print all',
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        selected: null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print selected'
            }
        ],
        select: true
    } );
} );

</script>
```

Comment: i am using this [plugin](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) for that purpose

Comment: Please provide more details or screenshot. To send selected data an page to another page/blade you can use session/cookie method... [datatable row selection](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html) now you can add a script for selected row fetch [fetch selected data](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data())

Comment: I'm afraid I cant post any screenshots yet, but still thank you for answering me, I'll try looking into it